Is there a better way to simplify below code using map reduce function?
enum ENUM_GROUP {
    GROUP1,
    GROUP2,
    GROUP3
}

export const mapGroups = (groups: string[]): ENUM_GROUP[] => {
    const hasGroup1 = groups.filter(group => group.endsWith('-group1'));
    const hasGroup2 = groups.filter(group => group.endsWith('-group2'));
    const hasGroup3 = groups.filter(group => group.startsWith('group3-'));
    let enumGroups: ENUM_GROUP[];
    if (hasGroup1) enumGroups.push(ENUM_GROUP.GROUP1);
    if (hasGroup2) enumGroups.push(ENUM_GROUP.GROUP2);
    if (hasGroup3) enumGroups.push(ENUM_GROUP.GROUP3);
    return enumGroups;
}

Example input: ['test-group1', 'group3-test']
Expected output: [GROUP1, GROUP3]

This will automatically add all enum values to the array since even an empty array is truthy. Did you mean to use Array.prototype.some() instead?

TypeScript enum types are transpiled to number values, so your output will be [0, 2] (as GROUP1 === 0 and GROUP3 === 2) - if you want the names instead then you'll need to change ENUM_GROUP to a string-enum - or to a string type (e.g. type EG = 'GROUP1' | 'GROUP2' | 'GROUP3').

I just noticed you use endsWith for group1 and group2, but startsWith for group3, but it doesn't match your expected output.

thanks for pointing out, have corrected input

What about "group3-group2"?

it would match both groups although my actual scenarios would not have such combo

This works for me on TypeScript Playground.
enum ENUM_GROUP {
    GROUP1,
    GROUP2,
    GROUP3
}

const mapGroups = (groups: readonly string[]): ENUM_GROUP[] => {

    return [ ...groups
        .map( g => 
            g.endsWith  ( '-group1' ) ? ENUM_GROUP.GROUP1 :
            g.endsWith  ( '-group2' ) ? ENUM_GROUP.GROUP2 :
            g.startsWith( '-group3' ) ? ENUM_GROUP.GROUP3 : null
         )
        .reduce( ( set, v ) => ( v === null ) ? set : set.add( v ), new Set<ENUM_GROUP>() )
    ];
};

//

const input = [
    "a-group1",
    "b-group1",
    "a-group3"
];

const output = mapGroups( input );
console.log( output );


More 【ａｅｓｔｈｅｔｉｃ】 plz
I'm really not a fan of having to wrap a nice call-chain in [...<expr>], so let's add toArray(), and the awkward v === null ternary can be replaced with a .filter() step:
declare interface Set<T> {
    toArray() : T[];
}

enum ENUM_GROUP {
    GROUP1,
    GROUP2,
    GROUP3
}

Set.prototype.toArray = function<T>( this: Set<T> ) {
    return Array.from( this );
};

const mapGroups = (groups: readonly string[]): ENUM_GROUP[] => {

    return groups
        .map( g => 
            g.endsWith  ( '-group1' ) ? ENUM_GROUP.GROUP1 :
            g.endsWith  ( '-group2' ) ? ENUM_GROUP.GROUP2 :
            g.startsWith( '-group3' ) ? ENUM_GROUP.GROUP3 : null
        )
        .filter( v => v !== null )
        .reduce( ( set, v ) => set.add( v! ), new Set<ENUM_GROUP>() )
        .toArray();
};

//

const input = [
    "a-group1",
    "b-group1",
    "a-group3"
];

const output = mapGroups( input );

console.log( output );


Original version:
This works for me on TypeScript Playground - though I don't like how it uses substring on every element, as that will cause string allocs and copying, even when it isn't necessary.
(Update: This code assumes endsWith is the only predicate. It won't work with startsWith.)
enum ENUM_GROUP {
    GROUP1,
    GROUP2,
    GROUP3
}

const mapDict = new Map();
mapDict.set( '-group1', ENUM_GROUP.GROUP1 );
mapDict.set( '-group2', ENUM_GROUP.GROUP2 );
mapDict.set( '-group3', ENUM_GROUP.GROUP3 );

const mapGroups = (groups: readonly string[]): ENUM_GROUP[] => {

    return groups
        .map( g => mapDict.get( g.substring( g.lastIndexOf( '-' ) ) ) )
        .reduce( ( set, v ) => ( typeof(v) === 'undefined' ) ? set : set.add( v ), new Set<ENUM_GROUP>() );
};

//

const input = [
    "a-group1",
    "b-group1",
    "a-group3"
];
const output = mapGroups( input );
console.log( output );

